# Cannot call method 'instance' of undefined

Tags: protovis

When using the following code;

```
var pvChart = new pv.Panel();
pvChart.width(200);
pvChart.height(200); 

var pvBar = pvChart.add(pv.Bar);
pvBar.data([1,2,3]);

console.log(pvBar.fillStyle());
```

I get the error;

> Cannot call method 'instance' of
>   undefined

It refers to the `pvBar.fillStyle()`. Using this I want to retrieve the bars fillStyle for later use. Can anyone tell me the reason of this error and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLVED

it was because I was requesting the fillStyle before the bar has been drawn..

Correct code;

```
var pvChart = new pv.Panel();
pvChart.width(200);
pvChart.height(200); 

var pvBar = pvChart.add(pv.Bar);
pvBar.data([1,2,3]);

pvChart.render();
console.log(pvBar.fillStyle());
```